# Select and Copy non blank cells in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy the nonblanks cells in my excel file to txt file. My data looks like:

```
1 2 3
1 2
1
1 2 3 4
```

So, if i select all and copy, txt file shows like the empty cells have data which is not something that i want.

I tried this:

- <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Go to special
- Constants
- Numbers

These commands selects the nonblank cells but I cannot copy them. Is there a way to copy them? I get:

> That command cannot be used on multiple selections.

Thanks

Comment: Are you copying more than one column?

Comment: yes, i am copying everything other than empty cells

Comment: Have you tried saving it as a .csv (Comma-Separated-Value)? I guess a better question would be, what is the final format you want in the text file?

Comment: The final format must be exactly like I provided above. Direct copy and paste from excel shows it like:                                   1 2 3 4                                                               1 2 space space and so on.

Comment: Do you have notepad++? You can perhaps use the regex find and replace to remove the extra tabs at the right after copy/pasting in txt. If it's acceptable for you to use notepad++, I'll put an answer.

Comment: is there any reason you arent using a macro?

Comment: I am not sure if I have notepad++. How can I make sure I have it? I probably don't have it. I am downloading now.

Comment: I can use macro, but i am not good at VBA

Answer (score 1):

If you got notepad++, you can use the regex find and replace to remove all the extra tabs at the end of a line.

Open the txt file in notepad++ and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

In find, put:

```
\t+$
```

In replace, leave it blank.

Then check the radio button for the search mode from 'Normal' to 'Regular expression'. After that, hit 'Replace All' and this should be it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream
Dim str As String

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\myTextFile.txt", True)

For i = 1 To 10
    For Each cell In Range("A" & i & "F" & i)
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            str = str + cell.Text + " "
        End If
    Next cell
    stream.writeline (str)
    str = ""
Next i

stream.Close

End Sub
```

all you gotta do is change what you wanted separated by ( the " " at the end of the str line) and the range you want ( i = rows 1 through 10 as is) and ("a" & i ":f" & i which indicates a through f, in this case for rows 1 through 10)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With Word as your text editor, copy Excel as is and Paste Special as Unformatted Text.   Replace ^t^t with ^t until no more replacements are made, then ^t^p with ^p.